# Mean Stack : Unable to bind the drop down using Angular 2 and Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, angular2-routing, mean-stack

Im using MEAN (MongoDB Express Angular Node) for binding my drop down in angular 2 with MonogDB values in the backend.

I have routes and models in node JS as follows:

**var\www\html\Express\nodeauthapp-master\routes\categories.js**

```
//Get all categories
router.get('/get',(req,res,next) => {
    //res.send('Get categories');
    Categories.getAllCategories((err,categories)=>{
    if(err)
    {
      res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to get categories'});
    } 
    else
    {
      res.json({success: true, mainCategories:categories});
    }
  }); 
})
```

**\var\www\html\Express\nodeauthapp-master\models\categories.js**

```
// Categories Schema
const CategoriesSchema = mongoose.Schema({

category_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }

});

const Categories = module.exports = mongoose.model('Categories', CategoriesSchema);

//Get all categories
module.exports.getAllCategories = function(callback){
  Categories.find({},callback)
}
```

IN Angular 2 im binding drop down like:

**blank-page.component.html**

```
<form role="form">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label>Select Category</label><br/><br/>
                <select [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" name="selectedObject" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled>--Select--</option>

                    <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
                </select>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

**blank-page.component.ts**

```
export class BlankPageComponent implements OnInit {

  category:String;
  public categories: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private addproductService: AddproductService,
              private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     const category = {
         categories: this.category

   }

  console.log(category);

  this.addproductService.loadData(category).subscribe(data => { 
      if(data.success){
        this.categories = data.mainCategories;
       console.log('Drop down binded');
    } else {
       console.log('Not binded');
    }
});

}
```

**addproduct.service.ts**

```
export class AddproductService {

   category: any;
  loadData(category) {

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.get('http://10.*.*.*:3000/categories/get', { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json());

  }
}
```

I Get Drop down binded from the console log , but in frontend, there seems to be no values binded.

When i hit the GET API url in postman, i get the categories list.

In the browser logs i get :  Object {categories: undefined}

My object has :  [image]

Comment: where are you assigning response to categories variable?

Comment: this is all i have done, could you please suggest what is that i have missed out!!

Comment: You need to define an array public categories: Array<any> = []; and then under if(data.success){ write this.categories = data.mainCategories;  try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: have updated the code as suggested, i get object object in the drop down, seems almost near...!

Comment: In you html do this                     <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.category_name">{{category.category_name}}</option>

Comment: Ah ha i forgot to fetch the name in html...Thank you so much...its working...:)

Comment: Can i post it as answer so that you may accept it ?

Comment: Yes sure...I will accept it

Comment: posted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML code to this :

```
<form role="form">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label>Select Category</label><br/><br/>
                <select [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" name="selectedObject" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled>--Select--</option>

                    <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.category_name">{{category.category_name}}</option>
                </select>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```